# how to talk to an asmx service using C++

Tags: c++, asmx

I have an existing asmx Web Service I need to acces from a native C++ implementation ( no it cant be c# ). What are my choices ( Visual Studio User here ) to do this as fast as possible ( anything that does the add aweb reference equivalent would be lovely )
Thanks

Comment: What about C++/CLI?  Would that be applicable?

Comment: sadly no. the issue is my dll is a plugin in Adobe. so just dont want the headache

Answer (score 2):

One great tool I used for this kind of thing is [gsoap](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~engelen/soap.html).

Answer (score 1):

For native C++ to do web services, you'll probably need to look at third party tools. There may be some Microsoft things available, but after Soap Toolkit I never wanted to bother with MS provided native code libraries again.

gSoap is a third party web service library for C++, and is free to use in most cases.  If you do need the commercial license, I believe it is around $100, and only the developer needs to pay it one time.  I've used it fairly heavily on both Windows and Linux, and it has always been consistently high quality.  I encountered a bug once in the WS-Security plugin, submitted a fix to the maintainer, and he accepted it within a day or two.

The ramp-up time is roughly a day or two to learn it.